# Linking /usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1... Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/Frameworks

Tags: python, macos

I am trying to re-install python3 on my mac using brew by 
`brew install python3`. 
But when proceeding to the the link step, it threw an error:

`The brew link step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
Could not symlink bin/2to3-3.5
Target /usr/local/bin/2to3-3.5
already exists. You may want to remove it:
rm '/usr/local/bin/2to3-3.5'
To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite python3
To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run python3`

But after using `rm '/usr/local/bin/2to3-3.5` and `brew link --overwrite python3`,
an other error occured:`Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/Frameworks`.

And I don't know why this happened, because I cannot see the `Frameworks` directory under `/usr/local/`.

Comment: Maybe `/usr/local` have read-only permissions on and `brew` cannot make a new file / directory? Try running the command with elevated privileges.

Comment: I was trying to solve this by using `sudo` but as `sudo` is depreciated in HomeBrew, I don't know exactly what I can do about it. Any specific suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

I managed to resolve this by manually creating Frameworks directory:

```bash
sudo mkdir /usr/local/Frameworks 
sudo chown `whoami` /usr/local/Frameworks
```

Answer (score 1):

As of writing, Homebrew requires the contents of `/usr/local` to be chown'd to your username. This doesn't seem like a great solution, but it works, and is evidently the recommended use.

See: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/9953#issuecomment-3800557

You can do:

```bash
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local
brew link python3
```

Comment: I get the following response even after doing `sudo su`: `chown: /usr/local/: Operation not permitted`

Answer (score 0):

I (believe I) resolved this by `chown`ing and `chgrp`ing everything in `/usr/local/Cellar` and then unlinking and relinking:

```
% brew link python3
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5... 
Error: Could not symlink bin/2to3
Target /usr/local/bin/2to3
is a symlink belonging to python@3.9. You can unlink it:
  brew unlink python@3.9
```

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:

```
  brew link --overwrite python
```

To list all files that would be deleted:

```
brew link --overwrite --dry-run python
brew unlink python@3.9
Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.12... 24 symlinks removed.
brew link python3    

Linking /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5... 25 symlinks created.

% python3 --version
Python 3.6.5
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).